# distinct() on specific column is not working in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to get rows where `rate_card_id` is different but is not working.

```
 $distinct_rows = RateCharge::where('customer_charge_id',$customer_charge_id)->distinct('rate_card_id')->get();
```

it is fetching all the rows where `customer_charge_id` matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$distinct_rows = RateCharge::where('customer_charge_id',$customer_charge_id)->groupBy('rate_card_id')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $distinct_rows = RateCharge::selectRaw('DISTINCT rate_card_id)')->where('customer_charge_id',$customer_charge_id)->get();
```